# Why are preinstalled apps so small?

Tags: applications

On Android 7 I have some apps preinstalled. I'm talking about fresh installed apps without user data:

- AOSP Keyboard - 152 KB
- Browser - 180 KB (org.lineageos.jelly)
- E-Mail - 288 KB  (com.android.email)
- Calendar - 116 KB (com.android.calendar)

Why are these app so small compared to some small apps I have installed

- Unit Converter Ultimate ~ 8MB

Comment: Are you sure it is KB ?

Comment: Thats what I see when I go to Settings => Apps

Comment: initially(after clean install/fresh ROM) it will be like that, after usage it will increase.

Comment: You are probably seeing *services*   like `com.xxx.zzz` please add a screenshot

Comment: @beeshyams In android nougat `Settings->Apps` shows app data below app name. The other person may be describing about this.

Comment: @RahulGopi : I don't have Nougat. If this is the case, suggest you answer on those lines :)

Comment: @beeshyams apps also are named com.xxx.yyy

Comment: Those typically are services not apps AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Android 7 **only shows space occupied from `/data`**.

This is my phone [OnePlus 5]. Using the same app AOSP Keyboard as example.

In settings it shows as 260KB, and

```
# du -sh /data/data/com.android.inputmethod.latin
24K     com.android.inputmethod.latin
# du -sh /system/app/LatinIME
19M     LatinIME
```

Personal guess: A normal user can't alter how much space an app takes in `/system`, so Android chooses to directly ignore it.

Comment: So is there any advantage for the rom maintainer to install these apps under `/system` ?

Comment: To utilize space under `/system` partition, I suppose.

Comment: @user27596 Elevated permissions (especially under `/system/priv-app`), and prevention of accidental removal of critical apps (imagine the scenario where you are not near a PC, have no input method and have no browser to download it with).